# Unable to stop service in Android and Unable to show Received messages in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

In my one activity I have a `ListView` and two `Buttons` named "Start Service" and "Stop Service"
on "Start Service". `StartServiceActivity.class` is called which `extends Service` and in the `onStartCommand()` method I used `sendBroadcast` and pass some data.

My third class `ServiceSecondActivity` which `extends BroadcastReceiver` 
receives messages and show it using `Toasts`

1. Now what I have to do is , getting the received data from
   `BroadcastReceiver` and show it on the `ListView`. I have done code
   but don't know where I place code of `BroadcastReceiver` object so
   that it runs,
2. I can't stop my Service with the "Stop Service" `Button`.

1) First Activity

```
public class ServiceActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ListView lstv;
Button bstart, bstop;
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
String data[];
private IntentFilter filter;
Messenger mService;
Boolean mBound;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.service_layout);

    bstart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);
    bstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStop);

    bstart.setOnClickListener(this);
    bstop.setOnClickListener(this);

    lstv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lst);

    broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         data = new String[] { intent.getStringExtra("name"),
                    intent.getStringExtra("message"),
                    intent.getStringExtra("TimeStamp") };

         ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
            lstv.setAdapter(adp);

        }
    };
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data : "+ data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    //registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);

    switch (arg0.getId()) {
    case R.id.bStart:
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                StartServiceActivity.class);
        startService(i);
        break;

    case R.id.bStop:

        Intent ii = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                StartServiceActivity.class);
        //unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);

        stopService(ii);

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
}
```

2) Class wchich extends Service

```
public class StartServiceActivity extends Service{

ListView lvl;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
int count=1;
Long stm;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public Context getApplicationContext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

    Notification notification=new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Service " + count++, System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent inte=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ServiceActivity.class);

    PendingIntent penIn=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, inte, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "Service ", "Service is running", penIn);

    startForeground(20, notification);      
}   
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

           stm=System.currentTimeMillis()+ 5*1000; 
            while (System.currentTimeMillis()< stm) {

                Intent ii=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ServiceSecondActivity.class);
                ii.putExtra("name", "abc");
                ii.putExtra("message", "Number"+ count++);
                ii.putExtra("TimeStamp", "TimeStamp :"+stm);
                ii.setAction("demo.example.app_5_1_15.CUSTOM_INTENT");
                sendBroadcast(ii);
            }   

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stu
    stopForeground(true);
    stopSelf();

    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

3) Class which extends BroadcastReceiver

```
public class ServiceSecondActivity extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    CharSequence csName=intent.getCharSequenceExtra("name");
    CharSequence csMsg=intent.getCharSequenceExtra("message");
    CharSequence csTime=intent.getCharSequenceExtra("TimeStamp");

    Toast.makeText(context, "msg : "+csName + " : " + csMsg +" : " + csTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

ERROR LOG

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ContextImpl.stopServiceAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1389)
at android.app.ContextImpl.stopService(ContextImpl.java:1359)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.stopService(ContextWrapper.java:455)
at demo.example.app_5_1_15.ServiceActivity.onClick(ServiceActivity.java:120)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

( I don't know english .)
1. I don't know but if you want to send data you can use `Message in android`.
2. Service is singelton so i can stop it with start it again but with different intent to stop it by itself.

in button:

```
Intent ii = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            StartServiceActivity.class);
            ii.putExtras("stop",1);
startService(ii);
```

in your service:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
if (intent.hasExtra("stop") ) {
    //stop it now
    stopForeground(true);
    stopSelf();
}else{
//.............
}
```

}

Comment: thnx for your reply, but still service is continue to start